# Reporting inaccurately % of folder(s) comparison for duplicates, what's wrong with my code?

Tags: c#

My issue, is with the progress counting. E.g. a folder with 4 identical files, except two different folders contain them. And when both are compared, the scan progress ends and exits at 25%. This isn't good, because regardless of how many files, the reporting should be accurate of how many processed all the way to the end of the total files.

**Here's an MVP:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

namespace mvp
{
    class Program
    {
        public static string ComputeHash(string filename)
        {
            using (HashAlgorithm algorithm = HashAlgorithm.Create("SHA1"))
            {
                try
                {
                    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open))
                    {
                        return BitConverter.ToString(algorithm.ComputeHash(fs)).Replace("-", "").ToLowerInvariant();
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }
        }

        public static bool CompareHash(string first, string second)
        {
            StringComparer comparer = StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase;
            return comparer.Compare(first, second) == 0;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int totalFiles = 0, 
                firstFolderFilesProcessedCount = 0, 
                secondFolderFilesProcessedCount = 0,
                totalDuplicatesFound = 0;

            string firstPath = @"";
            string secondPath = @"";

            DirectoryInfo firstDir = new DirectoryInfo(firstPath);
            DirectoryInfo secondDir = new DirectoryInfo(secondPath);

            List<FileInfo> FirstFolderFiles = new List<FileInfo>();
            List<FileInfo> SecondFolderFiles = new List<FileInfo>();

            Console.WriteLine("Initializing...");

            FirstFolderFiles = firstDir.GetFiles("*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToList<FileInfo>();
            SecondFolderFiles = secondDir.GetFiles("*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToList<FileInfo>();

            totalFiles = FirstFolderFiles.Count + SecondFolderFiles.Count;

            Console.WriteLine("Scanning...");

            foreach(FileInfo first in FirstFolderFiles)
            {
                foreach(FileInfo second in SecondFolderFiles) 
                {
                    if(CompareHash(ComputeHash(first.FullName), ComputeHash(second.FullName))) {
                        ++totalDuplicatesFound;
                    }

                    ++secondFolderFilesProcessedCount;
                }

                ++firstFolderFilesProcessedCount;
                int percentage = (firstFolderFilesProcessedCount + secondFolderFilesProcessedCount) * 100 / totalFiles;
                Console.WriteLine($"Progress: {percentage} %");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Above code in action:**
[image]

Comment: try `int percentage = ((firstFolderFilesProcessedCount + secondFolderFilesProcessedCount) / totalFiles) * 100 ;`

Comment: It works as you expect if you add ` secondFolderFilesProcessedCount = 0;` before `foreach(FileInfo second in SecondFolderFiles) `

Comment: @Seabizkit, Nope. Gave: **Initializing...
Scanning...
Progress: 0 %
Progress: 100 %
Progress: 200 %
Progress: 300 %
Found 2 duplicate files.**

Comment: @JohnSmith i edited my first had a mistake... have u tried as now..

Comment: If you study your code, you are counting `secondFolderFilesProcessedCount` for every loop in FirstFolderFiles, so your total is really `totalFiles = FirstFolderFiles.Count * SecondFolderFiles.Count;` (based on how you are performing your loops).

Comment: @LarsTech **secondFolderFilesProcessedCount** is within the **second foreach loop**!

Comment: @JohnSmith, LarsTech is correct..., side note it may be better/simpler to have it as a percentage of just the first loop and ignore the counting of the inner loop, so total is just the first folder and then percentage complete is just a count of the first loop in the normal (current / total) * 100.

Comment: @Seabizkit, sorry: Doesn't work. **Progress: 21 %** and with your second proposal I get 0% reported.

Comment: You need to decide if your progress will indicate the number of files processed or the number of comparisons completed. These are very different. If you are counting both inner and outer loops, you are counting the number of comparisons, so the denominator should be `totalComparisons = FirstFolderFiles.Count * SecondFolderFiles.Count;` (i.e. don't add; multiply).

Comment: @JohnWu, where?

Comment: Step through your code using VS debug, and look at the values of those variables you're using to calculate % complete, and you'll see for yourself why it's not working out.  Set a breakpoint at the end of the innermost loop and compare what you see with what you expect to see, especially on the 2nd or higher time through the loop.

Comment: @Gus, I been doing that for **4 days now**. I decided, to give up and come to *SO* to ask.

Comment: What are the values for `firstFolderFilesProcessedCount`, `secondFolderFilesProcessedCount` and `totalFiles` do you see when you get through the loop for the second time

Comment: @Gus, they vary depending on the folders and how many files are found inside the folders.

Comment: yeah, I figured-- I'm asking what you get when you run it.

Comment: A simple way to solved your problem is get rid of the `secondFolderFilesProcessedCount` variable.  Set  `totalFiles = FirstFolderFiles.Count;`, etc.

Comment: @Gus, FirstFolderFiles = **4**, SecondFolderFiles = **15**, totalFiles = **19**, secondFolderFilesProcessedCount = **60** (*if not reset*), firstFolderFilesProcessedCount = **4**.

Comment: OK, so already you can see that 20 is more than 100%, using your percent complete calculation, and we're only done with the first loop.  So, that means we're doing something wrong there.  If you're doing "files compared", the total should be 4 + 15 (19), but in order to compare 4 files against 15 files, you have to do 4 * 15 (60) comparisons.  So, if you want to keep incrementing secondFolderFilesProcessedCount, you'd need to calculate the number of comparisons total, which will be folder1Count * folder2Count

Comment: @Gus, how can I get this to report *progressly*, meaning, to occur as it moves forward?

Comment: start by calculating the total # of comparisons you'll need to make (multiply fileCount in folder 1 by fileCount in folder 2), then use that as the denominator for your percent complete

Comment: @Gus, I am getting **0%** and it completes ?

Comment: Must be something wrong with your numerator -- 0 divided by anything will be 0.  did you remember to increment it every time you compare files?

Comment: @Gus, it's NOT dividing by **0**

Comment: Changing from `totalFiles = FirstFolderFiles.Count + SecondFolderFiles.Count;` to `totalFiles = FirstFolderFiles.Count * SecondFolderFiles.Count;` gives **0%**

Comment: @Gus, it works now with correct **% percentage** reporting. However, it says that it scanned **60 items**, due to the multiplication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've taken your code and updated it to use comparison count for percent complete.  Note that we still report on the number of files compared, but also go one level deeper to describe how many files were in each folder.

Key changes have comments explaining what they're for.

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

namespace mvp
{
    class Program
    {
        public static string ComputeHash(string filename)
        {
            using (HashAlgorithm algorithm = HashAlgorithm.Create("SHA1"))
            {
                try
                {
                    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open))
                    {
                        return BitConverter.ToString(algorithm.ComputeHash(fs)).Replace("-", "").ToLowerInvariant();
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }
        }

        public static bool CompareHash(string first, string second)
        {
            StringComparer comparer = StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase;
            return comparer.Compare(first, second) == 0;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int totalCompares = 0, comparisons = 0, totalDuplicatesFound = 0;

            string firstPath = @"c:\zap";
            string secondPath = @"c:\zap2";

            DirectoryInfo firstDir = new DirectoryInfo(firstPath);
            DirectoryInfo secondDir = new DirectoryInfo(secondPath);

            List<FileInfo> FirstFolderFiles = new List<FileInfo>();
            List<FileInfo> SecondFolderFiles = new List<FileInfo>();

            Console.WriteLine("Initializing...");

            FirstFolderFiles = firstDir.GetFiles("*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToList<FileInfo>();
            SecondFolderFiles = secondDir.GetFiles("*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToList<FileInfo>();

            int firstCount = FirstFolderFiles.Count;
            int secondCount = SecondFolderFiles.Count;

            //Total number of compares; use for calculating percent complete
            totalCompares = firstCount * secondCount;  

            Console.WriteLine("Scanning...");

            foreach (FileInfo first in FirstFolderFiles)
            {
                foreach (FileInfo second in SecondFolderFiles)
                {
                    if (CompareHash(ComputeHash(first.FullName), ComputeHash(second.FullName)))
                    {
                        ++totalDuplicatesFound;  
                    }

                    ++comparisons;
                }

                // compares completed vs total compares to be done
                int percentage = (comparisons) * 100 / totalCompares; 
                Console.WriteLine($"Progress: {percentage} %");
            }

//Files Compared is only part of the story; 50 vs 50 is "harder" than 5 vs 95
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Files Compared:\n  {0}: {1}\n  {2}: {3}", firstPath, firstCount, secondPath, secondCount));
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} duplicates found comparing {1} total files", totalDuplicatesFound, firstCount + secondCount));
        }
    }
}
```

Sample Output:

```
Initializing...
Scanning...
Progress: 20 %
Progress: 40 %
Progress: 60 %
Progress: 80 %
Progress: 100 %
Files Compared:
  c:\zap: 5
  c:\zap2: 5
4 duplicates found comparing 10 total files
```

Answer (score 0):

below are to different ways to calculate.
The key being the first is how many comparisons have been completed.
Credit to LarsTech for point it out

1. Based on comparisons

totalDuplicatesFound = 0;

##########################################

```
var firstFolderFilesProcessedCount = 0, 
var secondFolderFilesProcessedCount = 0,

var totalCompare = FirstFolderFiles.Count * SecondFolderFiles.Count;

Console.WriteLine("Scanning...");

foreach(FileInfo first in FirstFolderFiles)
{
    foreach(FileInfo second in SecondFolderFiles) 
    {
        if(CompareHash(ComputeHash(first.FullName), ComputeHash(second.FullName))) {
            totalDuplicatesFound++;
        }

        secondFolderFilesProcessedCount++;
    }

    firstFolderFilesProcessedCount++;
    var current = firstFolderFilesProcessedCount * secondFolderFilesProcessedCount;
    int percentage = (current / totalCompare) * 100;
    Console.WriteLine($"Progress: {percentage} %");
}
```

##########################################

or

2. based on how many of the main list has been completed

##########################################

```
var firstFolderFilesProcessedCount = 0
var totalFiles = FirstFolderFiles.Count;

Console.WriteLine("Scanning...");

foreach(FileInfo first in FirstFolderFiles)
{
    foreach(FileInfo second in SecondFolderFiles) 
    {
        if(CompareHash(ComputeHash(first.FullName), ComputeHash(second.FullName))) {
            totalDuplicatesFound++;
        }
    }

    firstFolderFilesProcessedCount++;
    
    var current = firstFolderFilesProcessedCount;
    int percentage = (current / totalFiles) * 100;
    Console.WriteLine($"Progress: {percentage} %");
}
```

##########################################

Comment: Seabizkit, sorry, this doesn't work. Doesn't give the expected natural result.

Comment: @JohnSmith maybe a better explanation then of what you are expecting.
What is the count of FirstFolderFiles(x) and SecondFolderFiles(y).
lets say that x is 10 and y is 3, this means for the total number of loops which will happen is 30, even tho there are only 10 files in first folder(x). As you are not storing which folder have which files it will be doing every file against every file. if you are on your x loop, you could work out the % based on 1 loop and just set the percentage as its known. each loop = 1x3, so each loop is 3. aka on first loop what is the percentage (3%) for example